# c++ abstract classes constructor calls

Tags: c++, abstract-class

Can anyone explain to me the constructor calls, in the following code.
How is the constructor of abstract class called, when there exist no object for it but only a pointer to the derived class. Is an instance of it created to hold the vtable ?

```
#include <iostream> 

using namespace std;

class pure_virtual {
  public:
    pure_virtual() {
      cout << "Virtul class constructor called !"  << endl;
    }
    virtual void show()=0;
};

class inherit: public pure_virtual {
  public:
    inherit() {
      cout << "Derived class constructor called !" << endl;
    }
    void show() {
      cout <<"stub";
    }
};

main() {
  pure_virtual *ptr;
  inherit temp;
  ptr = &temp;
  ptr->show();
}
```

Comment: Derived classes' constructors call their base classes' constructors.

Comment: Thank, you sir ! damn I need to learn a lot

Comment: [Luckily there's good books that cover what you need to learn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: hey ! thank you for the suggestions !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constructor of the `pure_virtual` class is called when the constructor of `inherit` is called. So, when the line `inherit temp;` is executed, the constructor of the object is being called, because it is a derived class. Then the base class constructor is called first.

So in your case the output will be

```
Virtul class constructor called !
Derived class constructor called !
```

and because the `void show()` is virtual, the correct function is called, which is that of the `inherit` class.